# KeyCharacterMap in android code

Tags: android, dictionary, key, character

Can anyone explain me what is the main purpose of KeyCharacterMap in android?
Whether this can be used for handling KeyEvents??

Any Help??

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

with the use of characterMap one can put validation in edittext, or can search at runtime when a key is pressed or can put special function to a particular key when it presses?